# ModuleNotFoundError when running bash shell script, but works fine when running it in terminal with python

Tags: bash, shell, python, raspberry-pi

So I'm trying to run 3 separate discord bots together within 1 script.

The start.sh script looks like this;

```
node spamprevention/index.js > logs/spamprevention.log 2>&1 &
node reportbot/index.js > logs/reportbot.log 2>&1 &
python main.py


while :; do
    sleep 5
done
```

Within the directory `pi@tradehubrpi:~/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent` is where the `spamprevention` & `reportbot` folders are along with the `start.sh` and `main.py` files. I input `bash start.sh` in the terminal to start this script.

Here are the logs;

```
pi@tradehubrpi:~/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent $ bash start.sh
start.sh: line 1: logs/spamprevention.log: Permission denied
start.sh: line 2: logs/reportbot.log: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from discord import *  # import library
  File "/home/pi/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent/discord/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from typing import NamedTuple, Literal
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
^C
pi@tradehubrpi:~/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent $ sudo bash start.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import aiohttp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

The 2 javascript bots run fine, but for the python bot I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.
But when I run `python main.py` in terminal it works fine.

As you can tell by now I'm not a developer. Is there an easy fix for this? (Running these on a Raspberry Pi 4)

edits;
no logs for running `python main.py` which means it runs correctly, logs will show if theres an error or some type of action in discord.

when running `sudo python main.py` it returns this;

```
pi@tradehubrpi:~/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent $ sudo python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from discord import *  # import library
  File "/home/pi/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent/discord/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from typing import NamedTuple, Literal
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the command you use to start the script and the complete output. Do you start the script as the same user in the same working directory as when you start `python main.py`?

Comment: yes in the same directory `pi@tradehubrpi:~/discordbots/trade-hub-secret-agent $` is where I run `bash start.sh` and `python main.py`

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** and provide *all* requested information *in the question*. Don't use comments for this purpose. The complete output including the complete error message is still missing.

Comment: is there an issue with python path or something?

Comment: As you can see there are permission issues when you run the script as a normal users after running it as `root`, and Python behaves differently in these two situations. Now please also show what happens when you run `python main.py` and `sudo python main.py`. BTW: You should only run programs as `root` if this is absolutely necessary.

Comment: it runs fine when using `python main.py` but i get error when running as root. but regardless, when I run `bash start.sh` I get the `ModuleNotFoundError` - the permissions for the 2 others are an easy fix

Comment: So the obvious difference is that you start a new `bash` process which starts `python` instead of starting `python` from your interactive shell. Which of the startup files mentioned in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html exist on your system? Does any of the files contain any settings related to Python? Please also check the output of `type python` and also insert this into your shell script as a separate line before `python main.py` and run the script again.

Comment: so i changed `python main.py` in `start.sh` to this `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 main.py` and it seems to be working. thank you!

Comment: If the `python3` package is installed, then `python3 main.py` might also work.

Comment: well i remember changing paths a while ago so when using `python` it would be the latest version. so `python` is version 3.9 and `python3` is verison 3.7 - forget how i did all that, think it was something in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

Comment: I don't know if Python 3.9 is required for your script or if 3.7 (or even any 3.x)  would be sufficient. I suggest to prefer a packaged version over a local installation because this is easier to reproduce.